# Kendo.toString() returns wrong value for date parse

Tags: kendo-ui

Hi all I am using kendo library in my page.  I am parsing a date to get the month using the below code

```
  kendo.toString(new Date(2000, 1, 1), "M")  
and '
   kendo.toString(new Date(2000, 1, 1), "MM")
```

but the result shows me  `"01 February"`  and  `"02"`   respectivly.

what documentation says is

```
"M" - The month, from 1 through 12.
"MM" - The month, from 01 through 12.
```

But I am not sure why the month is going for feb instead of Jan. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct! Check `Date` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[image]

Months in JavaScript are 0 based which means that month 0 is January. In KendoUI "MM" format is the number of the month in 1 base (1 for January).

So the problem is that when you do `Date(2000, 1, 1)` you are saying February 1st, 2000.